# Edittext hint collapse

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have a layout that looks like this

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:hint="hint1"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="/"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:hint="hint2"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
```

The layout is aligned to right. Currently when I select *et2* and input 1 number, hint disappears but Textview and *et1* does not get closer to the right side of the screen leaving a gap between *et2* and textview. How can I solve this?

Comment: change orientation of your layout.

Comment: @Akp I need these 3 fields to be aligned on the right side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `addTextChangedListener` to your `EditText` for remove hint programmatically:

```
    et2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if(charSequence.length()==0)
                et2.setHint("hint2");
            else
                et2.setHint("");
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

check this once

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:hint="hint1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="/"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:hint="hint2"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Didn't change anything